# Problem sending data to a LED name badge through BLE using Bleak

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy

So I bought one of these cheap 11x48 LED name badges at FosDem the other week, and I want to update the display over BT using Python in macOS.

The badge can be programmed either via a mobile app (there are some variants that work, I use ["Mini LED Badge" for iOS](https://apps.apple.com/se/app/led-badge/id1461761458?l=en-GB)), or tethered to a PC using for example [led-name-badge-ls32](https://github.com/jnweiger/led-name-badge-ls32), since the badge apart from BLE connectivity will present as a USB-HID device when connected to a USB host. The script works fine, but I want wireless.

This is not uncharted territory, Gautier Mechling wrote an Android app and [a very useful article](https://nilhcem.com/iot/reverse-engineering-bluetooth-led-name-badge) about it. In this article, Gautier describes how they sniffed the BT packets sent to the device using WireShark, and that to make the badge say "Hello" there are 8 write requests sent to the characteristic `0xFEE1` of the service `0xFEE0` on the device.

As a test I tried sending the first write request (`77616E67000000000000000000000000`) to `0xFEE1` from my phone using the iOS app "nRF Connect". The badge reacted by switching from BT mode to display mode, with the displayed text unchanged (as expected).

As a first step, I want to reproduce this behaviour with Python using the module [Bleak](https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/tree/develop). This is what I came up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient

ADDRESS = "73126DE7-CA71-8C6C-BCB2-00BF482E2AD7"
FEE1_CHARACTERISTIC = "0000fee1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"

WRITE_REQUESTS = [
    "77616E67000000000000000000000000",
    "00050000000000000000000000000000",
    "000000000000E10C06172D2300000000",
    "00000000000000000000000000000000",
    "00C6C6C6C6FEC6C6C6C600000000007C",
    "C6FEC0C67C000038181818181818183C",
    "000038181818181818183C0000000000",
    "7CC6C6C6C67C00000000000000000000"
]

async def main(address):
    async with BleakClient(ADDRESS) as client:
        print(f"Connected: {client.is_connected}")
        byte_array = bytes.fromhex(WRITE_REQUESTS[0])
        await client.write_gatt_char(FEE1_CHARACTERISTIC, byte_array, response=False)
        await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
        print(f"Written bytearray: {str(byte_array)}")

asyncio.run(main(ADDRESS))
```

Output of the above:

```
Connected: True
Written bytearray: b'wang\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I expected this code to elicit the same behaviour in the badge as when I sent the same write request using nRF Connect, but the device won't react whatsoever. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

*Footnote: I'd like to add that I'm a complete noob when it comes to bluetooth, so please ELI5!*

Comment: You might want to take a look at the Bleak Troubleshooting guide: https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html There is also the example `service_explorer.py` to check you are finding the device and seeing the correct services https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/develop/examples/service_explorer.py

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track, @ukBaz!
I checked the traffic using PacketLogger and realized the response is actually used in some way, and needed for it to work. The script now runs perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Using PacketLogger in macOS (after a pointer from @ukBaz in the comments) I realized that `response` should be set to `True` and now it works perfectly.

Here is the updated code to display the text "Hello" on the badge:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient

ADDRESS = "73126DE7-CA71-8C6C-BCB2-00BF482E2AD7"
FEE1_CHARACTERISTIC = "0000fee1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"

WRITE_REQUESTS = [
    "77616E67000000000000000000000000",
    "00050000000000000000000000000000",
    "000000000000E10C06172D2300000000",
    "00000000000000000000000000000000",
    "00C6C6C6C6FEC6C6C6C600000000007C",
    "C6FEC0C67C000038181818181818183C",
    "000038181818181818183C0000000000",
    "7CC6C6C6C67C00000000000000000000"
]

async def main(address):
    async with BleakClient(ADDRESS) as client:
        print(f"Connected: {client.is_connected}")
        for i in range (0, len(WRITE_REQUESTS)):
            byte_array = bytes.fromhex(WRITE_REQUESTS[i])
            await client.write_gatt_char(FEE1_CHARACTERISTIC, byte_array, response=True)
            print(f"Written bytearray: {str(byte_array)}")

asyncio.run(main(ADDRESS))
```